# Почему 2 одинаковых фрейма оказываются не равны?

Tags: python, pandas, анализ-данных, openpyxl

Сравниваю 2 фрейма вывожу и несовпадения в третий:

```
df = pd.read_excel(self.filename1, skiprows=2, header=None, usecols=[3, 4, 5, 20]).drop(labels=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],axis=0)
df1 = pd.read_excel(self.filename2, header=None, usecols=[3, 4, 5, 12]).drop(labels=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14],axis=0)

result = df.loc[df1.ne(df).any(axis=1)]
```

В консоль выводит:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всё одинаково, но выводит в третий как разные записи. В чём может быть причина?
Пример таблиц https://transfiles.ru/8lqqy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С точки зрения Pandas, в этих двух фреймах нет **ни одного** совпадения:

```
In [38]: df
Out[38]:
          3     4     5     20
11     Ручка  17.0  12.0  12.0
12  Карандаш  18.0  33.0  14.0
13  Тетрадка  19.0  45.0  16.0

In [39]: df1
Out[39]:
          3     4     5     12
15     Ручка  17.0  12.0  12.0
16  Карандаш  18.0  33.0  14.0
17  Тетрадка  19.0  45.0  16.0

In [40]: df1.ne(df)
Out[40]:
      3     4     5     12    20
11  True  True  True  True  True
12  True  True  True  True  True
13  True  True  True  True  True
15  True  True  True  True  True
16  True  True  True  True  True
17  True  True  True  True  True
```

значения индексов различаются - этого достаточно для "несовпадения", не говоря уже о несовпадающих наименованиях столбцов.

PS Pandas во время сравнения делает выравнивание по значениям индекса и по наименованиям столбцов. Иначе мы бы не могли сравнивать фреймы с несовпадающим порядком строк или столбцов.

---

> как реализовать сравнение одинаковых данных, но с разной структурой
> таблиц чем воспользоваться?

Если у вас совпадает порядок строк и столбцов, тогда можно сравнивать фрейм с Numpy матрицей - в этом случае Pandas не будет делать выравнивание по индексам и столбцам:

```
In [47]: df.eq(df1) # сравниваем два фрейма
Out[47]:
       3      4      5      12     20
11  False  False  False  False  False
12  False  False  False  False  False
13  False  False  False  False  False
15  False  False  False  False  False
16  False  False  False  False  False
17  False  False  False  False  False

In [48]: df.eq(df1.to_numpy())  # сравниваем фрейм с Numpy матрицей
Out[48]:
      3     4     5     20
11  True  True  True  True
12  True  True  True  True
13  True  True  True  True
```

Comment: Хотел уточнить вы индексами называете вот эти числа 11, 12, 13 с  боку?

Comment: @АполлинарийКодоправ, да, это значения индексов

Comment: Подскажите как реализовать сравнение одинаковых данных, но с разной структурой таблиц чем воспользоваться?

Comment: @АполлинарийКодоправ, дополнил ответ

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста в тему вопроса если у меня матрица изменится нужные данные будут в таблице но в другом столбце который находится в начале таблицы со сравниваемой, что можно сделать в данной ситуации?

Comment: @АполлинарийКодоправ, советую открыть новый вопрос с соответствующим примером данных и желаемым результатом